# CSS: extend the text background to the container width

Tags: html, css

I have a text in a cell, I want to make a background color, but I want that the color width takes the width of the container div, not of the text.
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
<span class='section'>Remove Members:</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section{
  background-color: #f7a7af;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `display` of span to `inline-block` because by default `span` has `display: inline` and you cannot set width on inline elements.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.section {
  background-color: #f7a7af;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-4'>
  <span class='section'>Remove Members:</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either set section span style to display:block/inline-block or use a div instead of a span.

```css
.section{
  background-color: #f7a7af;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-4'>
<span class='section'>Remove Members:</span>
</div>
```